# How to emulate a browser preferably usinng Python or a Linux tool

Tags: http, browser

I have the URL / Request Header / POST contents . Is it possible for me to sent the query to the server and get the output HTML and Javascript ?
This is a AJAX stuff , but still I think we can emulate using HTTP .

Is there a convenient method for this using Python ? Or is there a GUI tool , 
that would just lee enter the all the REQUEST HEADER options and also the POST contents and get the desired output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On perl you have LWP::UserAgent module. Python have sth similar urllib2 (it should be in core libraries). You may also need "Beautiful Soup" for html/xml parsing.

Comment: Will look at urllib . I am not looking for parsing , basically I am trying to reproduce the server side issues for which I dont need HTML to be rendered - HTML output would be error page most of the cases which I am checking .

Answer (score 1):

You can use "wget" which should be available for most distros.

Read up on --post-file and --header.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget

Answer (score 1):

In Python you also have Google's httplib2 which has a higher level interface than urllib2.
For further detail see [Python urllib vs httplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305250/python-urllib-vs-httplib)