# What is the difference between Python's httplib and urllib2?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, httplib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python urllib vs httplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305250/python-urllib-vs-httplib)

I am just curious when I would want to use **httplib** over **urllib2** and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically - httplib is lower level, while urllib is high-level.  Use urllib2 whenever you just need to do something basic, like read the contents of a web site.   Use httplib when you need to do something more crazy (hopefully rarely).

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna give [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) a look instead of urllib2 if you want to do some higher level HTTP code. httplib is rarely used directly.