# http.client.HTTPConnection.request vs. urllib.request.Request

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, urllib, http.client

urllib.request and http.client are both python standard libraries. The docs for the relevant method from the former is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) and the latter, [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.request) (am using 3.5)

Does anyone know why they have 2 methods within the standard libraries which appear to do the same thing, or what the difference between them is?

Reason for asking, is that I am working on merging some classes with the goal of sending a POST request of `content-type` `multipart/form-data` using Python standard libraries only. There is a question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270518/python-standard-library-to-post-multipart-form-data-encoded-data) with a [link to code](https://pymotw.com/3/urllib.request/#uploading-files) with a class which does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see:
[Python urllib vs httplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305250/python-urllib-vs-httplib)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I feel that since that's a 13 year old discussion and a lot has changed (e.g., there is no urllib2 anymore), an updated discussion on this is warranted IMHO